# Bluetooth 2.0 Serial connection with RN270 and IOGEAR GBC232A

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, serial-port, rfcomm

I am currently trying to read data from a sensor at 100Hz at Baud 115200 with each frame at 60 bytes, while connecting the sensor through Bluetooth 2.0 adapter that is set as slave. The reading of the data only works for approximately 5 seconds before there will be no data to be fetch from Ubuntu's /dev/rfcomm0.

However the Bluetooth connection is still live as it indicated by the lights on the adapter and hcitool command and from my calculation Bluetooth 2.0 should be able to handle at this speed. Does anyone know what could be the possible cause of this and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to understand what is a `MCVE` . Can you make sample code (inputs and required outputs if appropriate, tiny!), so people that know this subject can easily copy/paste into their programming environment and see your problem on their machine in less than a minute. OR at least include your code and config that is failing. You also need to swap one of your tags at the bottom to include a tag for the programming language you are using. My only comment would be to try 1/2ing the speed and see if that fixes your problem or only doubles the time-to-failure. Readers would want to know. GoodLuck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.